# What is the exact behavior of ^ references when passed to a function?

Tags: function, reference, parameter-passing, c++-cli

I am completely new in C++/CLI. I have programmed before with C++.

I was reading a book and saw that if I pass a `String^` **str** as an argument to a function, and write **str = "New String"**  inside the function,  The string **str** doesn't changes value to "New String" after returning to main.

The ^ was supposed to behave kind of similar to pointer in C++, so I was expecting **str** to change value.  What happened here?

I tried also another experiment with `List<String^>^`.  If I write this code:

[image: Code Sample]

My output is:

```
1
2
CHANGED string
```

So it seems like it behaves sometimes like a reference/pointer in C++ (in the List case) but sometimes it behaves like passing by value (in the String case).

Could someone explain to me what is going on in each case?  Thanks in advance. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, like a pointer.  The syntax sugar might be a bit confusing, `str = "asdf";` looks like a value is getting assigned.  Not what happens (string objects are immutable), it in fact creates a new object.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh so its similar to Python I suppose?  Changing anything inmutable will create new object while changing mutable works as usual.  Thanks Hans.